# How do I use subl (Sublime Text) to edit mercurial commit messages

Tags: mercurial, sublimetext3

I'm having trouble using sublime text to edit my mercurial commit messages. I tried setting the following in my dotfiles:

```bash
export HGEDITOR=subl
```

This opens sublime correctly with a window including the commit summary, but after I save the file and close it, when I return to my terminal I see the error

```bash
abort: empty commit message
```

and the change goes uncommitted. How can i use sublime text for my `HGEDITOR`?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `subl` is returning before it has finished writing the commit message. You can solve that by changing your bash/zsh/etc export to read

```bash
export HGEDITOR="subl -w"
```

(note the quotes). The `-w` flag tells sublime to first save the contents and then return. Oftentimes, people will pair this with the `-n` flag which opens sublime in a new window (outside of any current project/folder).

Comment: You don't have to export the env variable you can also just set at `[ui]` `editor = "subl" -w`